# events not working on custom shapes in kineticjs

Tags: kineticjs

I have drawn custom shapes in kineticjs using Kinetic.Shape and then I am tring to attach mouse events to this shape. However the event is never firing:

```
var myShape = new Kinetic.Shape({
      drawFunc: function (canvas) {
              var context = canvas.getContext();
              context .beginPath();
              context .moveTo(47.1, 139.8);
              context .lineTo(50.5, 137.6);
              .
              .
              .
              context .closePath();
              context .fillStyle = color;
              context .fill();

          },
          fill: '#2369e7',
          stroke: 'black',
          strokeWidth: 2
      });

myShape.on('mousedown', function ()
      {
          //this never fires
      });
```

I tried events with Circle and Rectangle like the sample documents and it works. However with Kinetic.Shape objects, the events never fire. Any idea?

Comment: perhaps there's something like a `containsFunc` that you need to implement as well?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it by adding this at the end of drawFunc:

```
canvas.fillStroke(this);
```